# Connect Power BI to Angular App through MSAL

Tags: javascript, angular, powerbi, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have been trying this from months and still I did not find any solution on how to authenticate user with PowerBI service along with the Microsoft Authentication using MSAL.

Tried with https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/ this url as well in powerBI endpoint

```
export const protectedResources = {
    powerBI: {
        endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        scopes: ["Report.Read.All"],
    },
    graphMe: {
        endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
        scopes: ["User.Read"],
    },
    armTenants: {
        endpoint: "https://management.azure.com/tenants",
        scopes: ["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
    }
}
```

Above the scopes code in config and below is the code got from Microsoft documentation which is working perfectly fine for Authenticating user with graph api and able to get user details.

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
}


export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();

  protectedResourceMap.set(protectedResources.graphMe.endpoint, protectedResources.graphMe.scopes);
  protectedResourceMap.set(protectedResources.armTenants.endpoint, protectedResources.armTenants.scopes);
  protectedResourceMap.set(protectedResources.powerBI.endpoint, protectedResources.powerBI.scopes);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: loginRequest
  };
}
```

But the Problem is after user gets authenticated still user has to click on additional sign in button inside the iframe in order to again get authenticated with PowerBI.

[image]

See the image.

Please provide me a way to authenticate user in one shot just by single login I should be able to login user in both my app and powerBI service.

Answer (score 0):

You can find instructions for the Power BI APIs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/

Note that the Power BI APIs are on https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/ (not graph.microsoft.com) and scopes will be similar to `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/<scope name>`

Follow the instructions to add PowerBI to your application in the Portal, and then you should be able to configure MSAL to acquire tokens with relevant scopes for each PowerBI endpoint you use.

For example:

```js
powerBI: {
        endpoint: "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports",
        scopes: ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All"],
    }
```